# Which wallet can I use to store all my cryptocurrencies ?

Tags: wallet, litecoin, ethereum, zcash

I'm new to cryptocurrencies and I would like to store all my currencies (I read here and there that it is not safe to store everything on Coinbase).

So I tried Coinomi which seems quite good but is it safe ? Since I can send everything with only a password (not even with fingerprint or a pin), did anyone had an issue with it ?

I was also wondering, since I have Zcash, Bitcoin, LiteCoin et Ethereum, how is that possible that I can backup all these currencies with only 1 passphrase ? I mean, if I download the Zcash app for Mac OS, how will I recover my coins ?

Thank you !

Comment: Coinomi has a problem: It's not open source https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/6rbzwm/just_noticed_coinomi_android_wallet_is_not/

Answer (score 1):

[Jaxx](https://jaxx.io/) is a multi-currency wallet. Hardware wallets like [Trezor](https://trezor.io/) and [Ledger](https://www.ledgerwallet.com/) support multiple currencies as well.